# Firebase: What are the minimum permissions that should be granted to deploy only?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, firebase-console, google-iam

With Firebase: What are the minimum roles/permissions that should be granted to allow someone to deploy only?

I am not the owner of the organization, but I can create projects. I have gone through all the permissions, documentation, and it's not clear at all what the minimum permissions would be, there is no 'deploy only' permission, it's quite confusing.

We are using hosting only, no database, no other product, other than hosting a web application.

I want to restrict to just this, not allowing to use any other Firebase resource, just to deploy the web app.  (firebase deploy only)

*Provide background including what you've already tried*

I have spent three hours reading documentation.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Firebase support, who will escalate to engineering if they don't know the answer?  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I did, but have not heard back.

--
There is a feature in Firebase called 'Hosting', but there are no IAM permissions in the pick list to grant privs to this 'Hosting' product.

There should exist these to chose from for each hosting web app:
 * Firebase Hosting Admin
 * Firebase Hosting Editor   (deploy only, cannot create new hosting, delete existing hosting, or create any other services outside of hosting, just update)
 * Firebase Hosting Viewer

Answer (score 2):

Google does not provide any way to limit permissions to allow a developer or contractor to deploy only ('Hosting Editor' permissions is what I am looking for).

They can calculate Pi to 31.4 trillion digits, do a lot of other amazing things, but not allocate minimal resources to make Firebase an Enterprise ready product.